# How to make a variable loop in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, loops

I'm trying to make a loop that won't crash my flash application. I want variable CN to go from 1 to 10, and then 10 turns into 1 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1....). This is what I have so far...

```
var CN:int = 1;
for(int CN = 1; CN<100; CN++);

NumberCounter.text = String(CN);
```

Please help. I don't get this at all :( I'm a novice programmer so a lot of things I do won't make much sense.

Comment: What do you mean by 'turns into 1'? Do you mean starts over or just puts 1 at the end?

Comment: Do you have a maximum number of times you need it to start over? If not, the app will just get caught in an infinite loop. Perhaps if you give a few details about the purpose of this, we can recommend a more appropriate approach to the problem.

Comment: BTW, in the code snippet above, I don't think you need the 'var CN:int=1;' You are creating it again in your FOR statement.

Comment: I'm in awe of this question/answer. The goal being to achieve an infinite loop. Surely taking the time to learn about the basics of a for loop is more efficient and beneficial for learning than what we have here. - http://dev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-loops--active-1878 -- via google search for "as3 tutorial for loop"

Comment: @prototypical - I think you should consider replacing your cynicism with understanding. For a 'novice' programmer, it can be difficult to know how to approach these types of problems. I know from my own experience, when I first started programming, it took some time to learn about resources like Google and 'tutorial'.

Comment: It's not cynicism. I think this site is found by most via google, so don't think it's cynical to suggest that people are indeed capable of utilizing such a tool. More often than not, it seems they are well aware of the resources, but want to ask a direct question instead of taking time learn a concept the right way. Google is not a mystery.

Comment: If everyone learning decides to skip the step of actually taking time to utilize a book or tutorial that goes over very basic concepts, then sites like this get overloaded with the SAME questions over and over. That's the case to a large degree, but it doesn't have to be that way. My comment gives the proper suggestion that will most efficiently help this poster, and you, if you choose to consider it's validity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Numberofwins = 0;

CN.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);

function checkFrame(event:Event):void{
if(CN.currentFrame == 11){
    CN.gotoAndPlay(1);
    }
}

    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

Submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, CheckIf8);

function CheckIf8(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(CN.currentFrame == 8) 
    {
            Numberofwins++;
        trace (Numberofwins);
        Scorebox.text = String(Numberofwins);
    }



    else
      {
    gotoAndStop("Loose1");
      }
}
```

This was my solution

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear. Are you trying to go from 1 to 10 then from 10 to 1 once (20 steps) or to go back and forth between 1 and 10 in 100 steps ?

If it's the first, you can try something like this:

```
for(var i:int = 0, j:int = 0; i < 20; i++){
   if(i < 10) j++;
   else       j--;
   trace(j);//put this in your text field
}
```

if it's the second:

```
for(var i:int = 0; j:int = 1, k:int = 0; i < 100; i++){
   if(i % 10 == 0) j *= -1; //every 10 steps flip (multiply by -1) the increment direction(increase/decrease)
   k += j;//increment k based on j which will either increase or decrease
   trace(k);//use this value
}
```

However the textfield will update right away. If you want to display this change in time you can use the ENTER_FRAME event to increment (rather than the for loop) or a tween engine to animate the value

Comment: Its ok I decided to do something else instead of a variable loop. But this is great advice for next time :D

Answer (score 0):

For an infinite loop:

```
while(true){

  for(var CN:int=1; CN <= 10; CN ++) NumberCounter.text = String(CN);
}
```

To do it 10 times, which looks like your code is hinting at:

```
for (int x= 0; x< 10; x++){

 for(var CN:int=1; CN <= 10; CN ++) NumberCounter.text = String(CN);
}
```

Comment: ya but how will CN turn into 1 when it reaches 10 in the while example?

Comment: Because true can never be false, the while statement will repeat till the end of time(or until you close the app). Each time it repeats, it runs the for 1-10 again.

Comment: I got some errors. They are: expecting semicolon before CN (line 3), and expecting identifier before rightbrace (line 4). My code is:

var CN:int = 1;
while(true){
 for (int CN=1; CN <= 10; CN ++)
}

NumberCounter.text = String(CN);

Comment: YOur code is different than what I posted. Please look at it again and you will see you have NumberCounter.text.... in the wrong place.

Comment: Ok I fixed my text and now all I get is expecting semicolon before CN (line 4)

Comment: This is all my code:
var CN:int = 1;
while(true){

  for(int CN=1; CN <= 10; CN ++) NumberCounter.text = String(CN);
}

Comment: Okie First, you don't need the varCN:int = 1. this is redundant. There are no line numbers. What code is at line 4?

Comment: Line 4 is:   for(int CN=1; CN <= 10; CN ++) NumberCounter.text = String(CN);

Comment: and also what do you mean I don't need the var thing should I remove it or what should I replace it with?

Comment: You just don't need it. It is being created in your for statement; Okie. too early in the morning. It should be: for (var CN:int = 1; CN <= 10; CN ++)

Comment: Sorry for the wrong syntax there. I've been working with C# a lot lately.

Comment: It still says the same error. I erased my first line of code which was var CN:int = 1;, and all I have is:
while(true){
 for(int CN=1; CN <= 10; CN ++) NumberCounter.text = String(CN);
}

Comment: You just posted the same code as before. I have updated my answer with an example that I just tested.

Comment: I fixed everything but now the game lags and it wont go to the frame with the code in it. It just freezes when I click play (play leads to the frame with all the code). Is there a way I can make the numbers go slower? Because I think that's the problem (that the numbers are going too fast.

Comment: As I mentioned, it is in an infinite loop, the app will not proceed. I think you should look at ENTER_FRAME event or using a timer to do this part.

Comment: Ok I fixed this all by making something else instead of a variable loop. Thanks a lot for your help though, it is hard to find someone who can help this much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

if(CN>1)
{

var CN:int = 1;
for(int CN = 1; CN<10; CN++);

NumberCounter.text = String(CN);
}
else
{
}